Is preforming a survey on topic?
From time to time, some users would post a survey to gather some statistics. For example, "How many Chinese characters an average Chinese know?"
The table below contains 71 idioms. Native Chinese speakers can simply scan it across by row and then by column to find all the idioms. There's not much challenge for them. But for non-native speakers who don't have the pattern-seeking ability for common phrases, it might be a tough task. I would like to know how many idioms different level users can find in the table below.
I presume the more advanced ones can find more than the less advanced ones?
Is it on-topic?

Across

 
求之不得 / 求之不得
樂不思蜀 / 乐不思蜀
人盡可夫 / 人尽可夫
不過不失 / 不过不失
據為己有 / 据为己有
以假亂真 / 以假乱真
血債血償 / 血债血偿
至高無上 / 至高无上
積德行善 / 积德行善
來者不善 / 来者不善
善有有報 / 善有有报
報仇雪恨 / 报仇雪恨
夢昧以求 / 梦昧以求
知法犯法 / 知法犯法
落花流水 / 落花流水
交朋結友 / 交朋结友
水深火熱 / 水深火热
柔情似水 / 柔情似水
水落石出 / 水落石出
出奇制勝 / 出奇制胜
得道多助 / 得道多助
心如止水 / 心如止水
夷為平地 / 夷为平地
火乘風勢 / 火乘风势
杯弓蛇影 / 杯弓蛇影
長驅直進 / 长驱直进
妖言惑眾 / 妖言惑众
交朋結友 / 交朋结友
不熟不做 / 不熟不做
退避三舍 / 退避三舍
耳熟能詳 / 耳熟能详
風燭殘年 / 风烛残年
見多識廣 / 见多识广
僧多粥少 / 僧多粥少
民不聊生 / 民不聊生
智勇雙全 / 智勇双全
巧奪天工 / 巧夺天工
自相殘殺 / 自相残杀
虛懷若谷 / 虚怀若谷
肚滿腸肥 / 肚满肠肥
蛛絲馬跡 / 蛛丝马迹
 

Down

 
血濃於水 / 血浓于水
得心應手 / 得心应手
手足情深 / 手足情深
深山野嶺 / 深山野岭
如火如荼 / 如火如荼
見仁見智 / 见仁见智
斬妖除魔 / 斩妖除魔
得不償失 / 得不偿失
忠言逆耳 / 忠言逆耳
以柔制剛 / 以柔制刚
情至義盡 / 情至义尽
熟能生巧 / 熟能生巧
虛與委蛇 / 虚与委蛇
上善若水 / 上善若水
水到渠成 / 水到渠成
有始有終 / 有始有终
落花流水 / 落花流水
水乳交融 / 水乳交融
藥石無靈 / 药石无灵
以德報怨 / 以德报怨
出類拔萃 / 出类拔萃
殘民自肥 / 残民自肥
水落石出 / 水落石出
無奇不有 / 无奇不有
不進則退 / 不进则退
勝者為王 / 胜者为王
秋毫無犯 / 秋毫无犯
舉一反三 / 举一反三
三山五嶽 / 三山五岳
矯揉做作 / 矫揉做作
作法自斃 / 作法自毙
地大物博 / 地大物博
明刀明槍 / 明刀明枪
 


I'm rather uncertain about this: it's the every answer is equally valid problem.  "My Chinese level is [blah] and I found [X] chengyu."  This has practical problems: (a) it's hard to describe one's Chinese level [users studying HSK6 might be like me and get 1 or 2], (b) some people might study chengyu, while others don't, (c) maybe they did(n't) look carefully, (d) does everyone give a separate answer?  I "surveyed" Reddit users once.

(PS. I went through it, and only found one 乐不思蜀 because it's a 三国杀 card.)

@Becky 李蓓 I believe you know many idioms on the list, just the way the characters mixing like this, you have a hard time spotting them. Check the list to see if I am right

Checked, but I'm afraid I knew just one (prior to reading)---I never really studied them.

@Becky My suggestion is you should study them.  Even in modern Chinese, idioms are very commonly used in daily conversation. It makes your speech sound more refine and can shorten your sentences considerably.
